# socket.io issue using sails.js

Tags: socket.io, sails.js

I am trying to use socket.io with sails js. I understood that it was pretty straighforward and that sails provided an available socket.io structure out of the box. Howeve When I try to connect to my sails server from a distant client using

```
io.connect(http://localhost:1337)
```

It makes my server crash with the message:

> /node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils.js:216
>     return 0 == str.indexOf('s:')
>                     ^
>   TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined

I am probably missing something but I don't understand what.... Any clue about this?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing some quotes in your io.connect() call, but I can't imagine that your client app wouldn't throw a syntax error if your code really was written like that. Verify you've got:

```
io.connect('http://localhost:1337');
```

Answer (score -1):

ahem... Did you had a look @ the doc : http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/sockets
this is quite self explanatory, but if you need any help

Comment: Yes I read it, the problem is that this documentation is not very clear about connection from external clients. I don't really understand where the socket actions are handled. In socket.io you just have to create a socket.on("connection") function and precise callbacks for received messages. In sails I just don't see where all this logic is handled...