# Node js + Sails js + websocket app crashing every few hours

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, sails.js

I am having a problem similar to [socket.io issue using sails.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444155/socket-io-issue-using-sails-js). Every once in a while (once per day, or even few hours, it varies), a visitor to the web site/app will crash Node, seemingly due to the way his websocket client tries to connect. Anyway, here's the crash log:

debug: Lowering sails...

```
/Volumes/Two/Sites/lsdfinder/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils.js:216
  return 0 == str.indexOf('s:')
                  ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined
    at exports.parseSignedCookie (/Volumes/Two/Sites/lsdfinder/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils.js:216:19)
    at Manager.socketAttemptingToConnect (/Volumes/Two/Sites/lsdfinder/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/sockets/authorization.js:35:26)
    at Manager.authorize (/Volumes/Two/Sites/lsdfinder/node_modules/sails/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:910:31)
    at Manager.handleHandshake (/Volumes/Two/Sites/lsdfinder/node_modules/sails/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:786:8)
    at Manager.handleRequest (/Volumes/Two/Sites/lsdfinder/node_modules/sails/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:593:12)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Volumes/Two/Sites/lsdfinder/node_modules/sails/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:119:10)
    at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2076:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:120:23)
    at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1966:22)
9 Oct 10:42:24 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

In config/sockets.js, authorization is set to true. Not sure what else to do, where to fix this. Any suggestions? I can read the Sails docs too, but this appears to be a problem in Express/Connect, no? Thanks.

...René

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that once every so often, a client will connect that has no cookies. Sails.js is using `util.parseSignedCookie()` from Connect without checking for errors, and therefore an error is thrown. This is what it looks like in Sails:

```
if (handshake.headers.cookie) {
  handshake.cookie = cookie.parse(handshake.headers.cookie);
  handshake.sessionID = parseSignedCookie(handshake.cookie[sails.config.session.key], sails.config.session.secret);
}
```

If you take a look into the `cookieParser()` middleware of Connect, you can see error checking is required:

```
if (cookies) {
  try {
    req.cookies = cookie.parse(cookies);
    if (secret) {
      req.signedCookies = utils.parseSignedCookies(req.cookies, secret);
      req.signedCookies = utils.parseJSONCookies(req.signedCookies);
    }
    req.cookies = utils.parseJSONCookies(req.cookies);
  } catch (err) {
    err.status = 400;
    return next(err);
  }
}
```

I've created a Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/hexacyanide/6938044) that fixes the problem, and will submit a pull request to Sails.js when I have the time. The Gist uses Connect's `cookieParser()` middleware to automatically handle errors. If you want to use this, modify this file in your modules folder:

```
node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/sockets/authorization.js
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. The Gist, however, appears to have some typos in it, and crashes the server. I replaced an corrected what seemed to be an obvious one at the top, but it still crashes with 

"Volumes/Two/Sites/lsdfinder/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/sockets/authorization.js:34
      cookieParser(handshake, null, function(err) {
      ^
ReferenceError: cookieParser is not defined
    at Manager.socketAttemptingToConnect (/Volumes/Two/Sites/lsdfinder/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/sockets/authorization.js:34:7)

Comment: I think I spelled `middleware` wrong. If correcting that doesn't work, try `var cookieParser = require('express').cookieParser(sails.config.session.secret)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing a crossdomain request, you could turn off authorization.

In ***site_dir/config/sockets.js*** set **authorization** to **false**. One way of doing it. You can also call your api with something like this

`bash
**http://localhost:1337?cookie=smokeybear**`

Its is in the comments on the sockets.js file.